# Need help to get the X-Intercept of this 2x−√x²+1

Tags: equation-solving

i am a senior high school student i need getting the X-Intercept . Because my teacher told us the answer but i can not get it right . **the answer is x=√3/3**

Comment: see [Documentation >> Solve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) and try `Solve[2 x - Sqrt[x^2 + 1] == 0,  x]`

Comment: Sorry i can not

Comment: Why? $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function:

```
 f[x_] := 2*x - Sqrt[x^2 + 1]
```

You can get the x-Intercept with:

```
sol = x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x] // First
(*-> 1/Sqrt[3]*)
```

Notice that

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Plot the result:

```
 Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 10},Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{sol, 0}]}]
```

[image: no description here]

Comment: I really thank you. How could you do that ??  Is it a program?? Can u tell me the name?

Comment: Since you posted in the Mathematica StackExchange I used [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)

Comment: How can i use it ??

Comment: You need to purchase a license. But since you are a student your school/university maybe already did that.